android::Looper::pollInner
in our project we are using Sentry as crash reporting tool. we have a high number of crashes, titled as "android::Looper::pollInner". it just shows a bunch of stacktrace lines that cannot help me to find the cause. any clue about the origins of this kind of crash? I guess it may be related to memory leak, but cannot test this guess, as crash does not happen on my device.


I found this exception on google play console and it had more information. the problem was with webview and I had to implement onRenderProcessGone callback in WebViewClient to handle crash.
